# Finding the sum of a specific column inside hash

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, file-upload, methods, sum

I am working on uploading a .tab file to the database and everything is going well accept after the upload completes, I want to calculate the item price from that upload alone and not from the whole table.  I will post my examples below. I will post one easy one to show what I am trying to do on a smaller scale and then I will post my upload action which is just trying to get a specific sum at the end of the action.

Easy example:

```
def find_whole_rev
  @total_price = NewTable.sum[:item_price]
end
```

which returns the sum of all the values in the table no problem. But to scale it down to just show the item price of the uploaded file I have:

```
 def import
   require 'csv'

   db = []
   CSV.parse(params[:file].read, {headers: true, col_sep: "\t"}) do |f|

    db.push(f.to_hash)
    NewTable.create(purchaser_name:  f.to_hash["purchaser name"],
                   item_description: f.to_hash["item description"],
                   item_price:       f.to_hash["item price"],
                   purchase_count:   f.to_hash["purchase count"],
                   merchant_address: f.to_hash["merchant address"],
                   merchant_name:    f.to_hash["merchant name"],

    ) 
       @upload_price = f.to_hash.sum[:item_price]
   end  
 end
```

Everything works great except I can not get the upload_price variable to populate with tho item price total of the uploaded file.  I am getting this error message:

```
no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer
```

Thanks for any advice and I will edit/post further information if needed no problem.  Thanks again and cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 def import
   require 'csv'

   db = []
   @upload_price = 0

   CSV.parse(params[:file].read, {headers: true, col_sep: "\t"}) do |f|

    parsed_hash = f.to_hash

    db.push(parsed_hash)
    NewTable.create(purchaser_name:  parsed_hash["purchaser name"],
                   item_description: parsed_hash["item description"],
                   item_price:       parsed_hash["item price"],
                   purchase_count:   parsed_hash["purchase count"],
                   merchant_address: parsed_hash["merchant address"],
                   merchant_name:    parsed_hash["merchant name"],

    ) 

    @upload_price += parsed_hash["item price"]
   end  
 end
```

Comment: Thanks I am getting this error from line:::::::::

@upload_price += parsed_hash["item price"],

String can't be coerced into Fixnum

Comment: @upload_price += parsed_hash["item price"].to_i